# Magento 1.9 API - How to do oauth admin authorization login page in android appilcation?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

Need to know the possible way to do oauth admin authorization in android. In web I can be able to do it by showing the login page in browser. once success authorization I can get access token in PHP code. I want to do the possible way to do this android.